# How can I properly detect the available C++11 features among GCC versions?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, noexcept

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++11 Feature Checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225451/c11-feature-checking)

I'm particularly interested in the case of `noexcept` specifications which seem to have littered the C++11 standard library with the introduction of GCC 4.7. In this case, detecting compiler version is adequate; is that the best mechanism to produce portable code?

```
#include <system_error>

class server_error_category : public std::error_category
{
  public:
    virtual const char* name () const {  ...  }
    //
    // fails beginning with gcc4.7, 
    // looser throw specifier ...
    // overriding 'virtual const char* std::error_category::name() const noexcept (true)

    ...
};
```

Comment: [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/libs/config/) will define the macro `BOOST_NO_NOEXCEPT` for compilers that do not support `noexcept` specifications. If you're concerned about portability with compilers other than GCC, I'd recommend letting Boost do the hard work for you.

Comment: @ildjam Gar, if only that weren't so recent!

Comment: You can do `#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(cxx_noexcept)` and you'll be guaranteed not to use noexcept on compilers that don't implement it. On the other hand you may not get to take advantage of noexcept on compilers that _do_ support it simply because they don't support the feature checking macros... (AFAIK __has_feature only works on Clang)

Comment: @bames53 : `__has_feature` is not standardized, it's merely a Clang-specific extension.

Comment: @ildjarn It's true that it's not standardized, but it's the sort of thing that should be a de facto standard.

Comment: @bames53 I'm fairly certain it's not available in gcc. I haven't been able to find any docs that say otherwise.

Comment: @DanAlbert It's not. However the feature has now been standardized in C++ [SD-6](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations)

Comment: @bames53 That paper describes an alternative to `__has_feature()` where each feature has its own macro in the format `__cpp_FEATURE_NAME`. Those are also only recommendations for addition to the next standard; they may be rejected.

Comment: @DanAlbert they are not recommendations for addition to the language standard: there are no plans to include them in ISO/IEC 14882. SD-6 instead stands on its own as the committee's recommendations for feature testing.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check whether `noexcept` is applied to a particular method in compile-time (instead of preprocessing-time), you could simply use the `noexcept` operator.

```
noexcept(std::declval<std::error_category>().name())
// return 'true' if the expression is 'noexcept'
```

and then you could make the method conditionally noexcept using the syntax

```
virtual const char* name () const
     noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<std::error_category>().name()))
{ ... }
```

You can't check whether a library supports noexcept is preprocessing time. Version checking is the only method.

But you could just throw in the `noexcept` anyway. It is valid for the subclass's override to be `noexcept` even if the base class is not.

```
virtual const char* name () const noexcept { ... }
// valid even in 4.6.
```

(Note that Boost.Config doesn't really help because `noexcept` is supported since 4.6 in the language, but the library usage appears in 4.7.)