# Checking for C++11 library features

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, libstdc++, libc++

What is a good way of checking for the presence of specific C++11 features of the **standard library**.

For compiler features I just went by the way of checking the compiler version for the (IMHO) major compilers (*VC++*, *gcc*, *clang* at the moment, maybe *Intel*) Although this is not the best and most flexible approach, I don't know of anything better yet, except for *clang* which has the really nice `__has_feature` macros.

But it's even worse for library features, which are not coupled that rigidly to the compiler. At the moment I want to use the same approach of checking the compiler version for *VC++* (where it's pretty easy, assuming it uses its own library). For *clang* I can at least use `__has_include` for large-scale header-based queries. Other than that I guess checking `__GLIBCXX__`'s value if defined might be a good idea, but then again I cannot find any information of what specific *libstdc++* versions introduced which features, other than what the current version supports.

The methods should be kept to preprocessor checks and the like, since I want to use it in a header-only library without any sophisiticated configure procedure and without using any third-party libraries (and yes, *boost* is third-party).

1. So what are my possibilities of checking for specific C++11 library features under those (pretty narrow) conditions. Maybe even on the scale of particular functions or types being declared?
2. If checking for the compiler or library version is still the best approach, where can I find detailed information about the particular C++11 features supported by a **specific** version of *libstdc++* (and maybe other important ones, *libc++* perhaps)?

FWIW at the moment I'm interrested in `<cstdint>`, C++11 `<cmath>` functions and `std::hash`, but this may change and is probably not of importance for the general approach.

Answer (score 9):

There is really nothing nice you can do here besides knowing which compiler in which version implements what and have the proper defines in place.

gcc has a [special table](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) for library functionality. The main problem of `__has_include` are of course additions to the standard that live in old includes. `libstdc++` also has the necessary includes, but that doesn't mean the necessary define to enable the content of those files. It also wont tell you anything about the actual amount of available implementation (which sometimes is incomplete).

As you have a header-only library this doesn't apply to you, but is still important: binary incompatibility between C++11 and C++03 can come back and bite you.

I seriously wouldn't approach any of that on my own and rather use [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html). Originally it only described language features but has now expanded to standard library headers.

Comment: The compilers are really lazy when it comes to implementing new features.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz No, not really. Microsoft, maybe.

Comment: Some of them are doing pretty well. Links: http://www.aristeia.com/C++11/C++11FeatureAvailability.htm

Comment: I already know this libstdc++ table, but it only shows the current version's support, or did I overlook something there? Of course, knowing the current version's status doesn't really help.

Comment: @pmr Microsoft just has more strict release policy than Gcc; the fact new version appears after a year, doesn't mean it will have less features than accumulated gcc or other compiler versions...

Comment: @ChristianRau Sorry, I just remembered that the table doesn't have version information. I also just remembered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095885/checking-for-availability-of-c0x-algorithm-additions).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It doesn't have to mean it, but in this case it does, since they are way behind, disregarding of the actual release frequency.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: The preview version of Visual Studio 2012 is a long way behind gcc 4.6 ert to C++11 support, that is to say the next version of the Microsoft compiler lags behind the previous version of gcc.

Comment: @JoeGauterin And that doesn't even take into consideration that we already have access to 4.8 and 4.7 has been released.

Comment: @ChristianRau, the libstdc++ C++11 status table for 4.7 is at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011 and for 4.6 is at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x and for previous releases is included with the source.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* write autoconf macros to check, and if you do, submit them to http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/
The only relevant one so far checks for complete coverage, not for individual features: http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_header_stdcxx_0x.html#ax_cxx_header_stdcxx_0x
But that fails the requirement for no complicated configure checks.

> Other than that I guess checking `__GLIBCXX__`'s value if defined might be a good idea,

Looking at the value of `__GLIBCXX__` is not useful, [it contains the date the version was released](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/manual/manual/abi.html) which tells you almost nothing about the version (e.g. 4.6.3 is released after 4.7.0 so has a later date in `__GLIBCXX__` but has fewer C++11 features.) When using libstdc++ with GCC you want to use the general GCC version numbers in `__GLIBC__` and `__GLIBC_MINOR__` for checking versions (in general you can only use a given version of libstdc++ with the GCC release it came with.)

**Edit:** Starting with GCC 7 there is a new macro defined by the libstdc++ headers, `_GLIBCXX_RELEASE`, which is defined to the same value as GCC's `__GNUC__`, but is still usable even when using the libstdc++ headers with non-GCC compilers.

> but then again I cannot find any information of what specific libstdc++ versions introduced which features, other than what the current version supports.

The libstdc++ C++11 status tables for previous releases are available online where all GCC docs live: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/

For 4.7 it's at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011 and for 4.6 it's at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x and for previous releases is included with the source (but the coverage in pre-4.6 releases is pretty patchy anyway.)

Some added features are listed in the release notes for each version, e.g. http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html (in the libstdc++ section)

**Edit:** For C++17 library support we now list which version first added the feature, so you only need to look at the latest docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z

> FWIW at the moment I'm interrested in `<cstdint>`, C++11 `<cmath>` functions and `std::hash`

They should be present in all versions of libstdc++ that have any C++0x/C++11 support.

Comment: Of course autotools are no option, but thanks for the rest of the answer. I also figured out the problem with `__GLIBCXX__` (why define such a useless macro anyway?), so I used `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` for gcc. But what to do when using libstdc++ with e.g. clang, since clang's own definition of `__GNUC__` is just useless, being set to 4.2.X?

Comment: Good questions. I don't know what the point of that macro is. We don't officially support using libstdc++ with other compilers, but it works (and I use it with clang myself) so feel free to file an enhancement request in GCC's bugzilla asking for some way to identify the library independent of the compiler. I'll have a think about how to do that cleanly (i.e. have it picked up automatically from the GCC version - we don't want to have to set it manually when a new GCC release is made.)

Comment: Oh, so you're actually the right one to address with this problem, didn't know that ;) Well, for now I just settled with using `__GLIBCXX__ >= 20080606` for *clang* hoping there won't be any gcc versions < 4.3 released anymore. I guess introducing a simple version macro similar to `__GNUC__` would really be a good idea, as there are probably (don't know, though) other compilers trying to use `libstdc++` by default on 'nixes, and knowing the release date is pretty useless when the version numbers don't increase chronologically.

Comment: There won't be any more releases < 4.6, so that should work OK.  The Intel compiler uses libstdc++ on GNU/Linux, and I guess the PathScale and Open64 compilers probably do too.