# Is there a preprocessor directive for detecting C++11 Standard library?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, libc++

Is it possible to determine if C++ standard library has C++11 support using a preprocessor directive?

I'm currently working on a project which uses the C++11 language dialect, but with the a C++ standard library without C++11 support (I need this to be able to link with non C++11 libraries).

I'm aware of that I can test of C++11 support using the `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L`, but in my case this will evaluate to true. I need to know about the C++ standard library support for C++11.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11886288/743214

Comment: *"I'm aware of that I can test of C++11 support using the `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L`"* - No, not even that. Given that most compilers only support a subset of C++11 (however large that subset may be, though), this `__cplusplus` macro is outright useless. Portably testing for standard features (be it language or library) is still an unsolved problem (although *attempts* to solve it are on their way, as *TemplateRex* points out in his answer).

Comment: To me, your problem sound like you need a configure tool like CMake or autotools. They do checks for you and generate a header which contains Macros you can evaluate. If you have only a library, you might request from your users to provide a macro - still a poor solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing for features is an active research direction for the Standard Committee going towards the next C++14 Standard (and beyond that). There is a Study Group 10 with its own freely accessible [mailinglist](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/features/) where current development is being discussed. For the next meeting, this [N3694 working paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3694.htm) has been submitted.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was on the iOS platform where the choice of C++ standard library was between `libstd++ (GNU C++ standard library)` and `libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)`. I ended up using the `_GLIBCXX_`. The complete code ended up being:

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_
template <class T>
T&& move (T& arg) noexcept {
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}
#endif
```

Comment: I assume you mean `__GLIBCXX__`, and do you mean `ifdef` not `ifndef`? Your test assumes that libstdc++ never has C++11 support, but that's not true, only the ancient version that comes with your Mac has no C++11 support.

Comment: ... a year later ... I actually ended up using my own manual preprocessor definitions instead of relying on automatic inspection of standard library .